# Integration by subtitution question.Does the function have to be continuous.

Tags: calculus, integration

All the theorems about substitution rule for definite integrals that I come across state, that if $f$ is a continuous function on $I$ and if $\phi$ transforms $[a,b]$ into $I$ and is continuously differentiable then $$\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$$ But only one source that I foundstates, that $f$ only has to be integrable in it's domain for the rule to apply. Is it true?

I'm asking because I want to use the subtitution rule in one of the theorems I'm trying to prove, but the only thing I know about my $f$ is that it's integrable, not that it's continuous and therefore the second version of subtitution rule would satisfy me, not the first one.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous you can produce a simpler proof by means of the fundamental theorem of calculus. But that is not necessary.

Comment: In [Justification for integration by substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4634339/21813), the version that I gave requires $f$ to have a antiderivative on $\phi[a,b]$ and the LHS to exist; in other words, $f$ is not asked to be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't write this as a comment, so I'm giving it as an answer.

Yes, the theorem is valid in that case. See the following paper for an even more general statement.

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-27/issue-1/The-Substitution-Theorem-for-Riemann-Integrals/rae/1212763969.full)