# Is the variable in an indefinite integral bound?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Take an indefinite integral on $f(x)$ is $x$ bound in this expression, as on the other side we get an expression that depends on $x$ for example $$\int f(x) dx = e^x+c$$

We get an expression that depends on $x$  but subsituting for $x$ in left -hand expression is entirely meaningless.

Comment: Substituting for $x$ on the right-hand expression is also pretty much meaningless. The way I view an indefinite integral $\int f(x)dx$ is the set of functions $F$ such that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question (though that's about derivatives) it's again a matter of quickly getting the point across, not formal correctness. See for example the first half of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2868217/568204) for an alternative way of writing it (obviously clunky and inconvenient for practical computations)

Comment: @peek-a-boo so we don't call it 'bound' even though to substitute into it is meaningless, it's sort of just a clunky expression/name for a value that is the anti-derivative of the function in the integrand, but we can't substitute into it? On the last question, it's not bound in the differential operator either?

Comment: No. the introduction of the letter $x$ everywhere is just a historic relic. If you want, you can define $\int f$ to denote the set (equivalence class) of all differentiable functions whose derivative is $f$, but this is highly non-standard.

Comment: Ok, but I see, but however we still have it equal to a number, also we have it's relation to the idea of a reimann sum, so can I view it as a way or referring to the general form expression for a function $g(x)$ where f$(x)=g'(x)$

Answer (score -1):

Note that, given the anti-derivative $g(x)$ of $f(x)$, an alternative expression reads

$$\int_b^x f(t) dt =g(x)+C$$
where $C=-g(b)$. So, compared to

$$\int f(x) dx = g(x)+C$$
$x$ may be viewed as a variable (indefinite) bound of the integral.

Comment: The OP is talking about a variable to be bounded (as opposed to a free variable), not about a numeric bound of the integral.